# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The following error appears when I import the keras library

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```

> ```
> AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute
> 'populate_dict_with_module_objects
> ```

I am working on windows 10 my keras version is: 2.4.3 and tensorflow version is 2.5.0rc0
I also installed cuda to solve the problem but it was not effective

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imports work perfectly with Tensorflow 2.4.1, Try this way

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```